# Segmentation Fault When using Realloc more than 3 times

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm just learn about memory dynamic, and did experiment, but still get stuck. already search some around, but didn't give any result.

This is my simple code :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

    typedef struct kata kata;
    struct kata {
        char string[256];
    };

void load(kata **data)
{
        int len = 0;

        while( len < 5 ) {


            (*data) = (kata *) realloc ((*data), (len + 1) * sizeof(kata));
            printf("copy A - %d\n", len);

            strcpy(data[len]->string, "A");
            len++;
        }
        getch();
}

int main() {    
    kata *data = NULL;

    load(&data);

}
```

and my question, why it's always segmentation fault (at 3) when i debug it ?

thanks a lot for your advice

EDIT :

Still don't know why the error occurs, but i've found the solution just now..

just modify data[len]->string to (*data)[len].string

any idea, why we call data[len]->string occur some random segfault ?

Comment: Regarding the question from your edit: `data[len]->string` and `(*data)[len].string` are two different things.  The first is equivalent to `(*(data[len])).string`.

Comment: Note that it's customary *not* to put "(SOLVED)" in the title of a question here if you've figured it out; instead, click the checkmark next to the answer that helped you most.

Comment: hehe, sorry.., okay i've already checked one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[len]->string` should be <s>`(*data)[len]->string`</s> `(*data)[len].string`

Comment: try your advice, still not works, the IDE says "Invalid type argument of '->'", thx anyway :D

Comment: Sorry, should be `.` not `->`. Changed that in the answer.

Comment: thanks dude, exactly same with the solution i've get it some minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why did the code not work for you. I tried a similar example and it worked.

```
int main(void)
{
  int *ptr = NULL;

  ptr=(int *) realloc(ptr, 1*sizeof(int)); cout<<"1"<<endl;
  ptr=(int *) realloc(ptr, 2*sizeof(int)); cout<<"2"<<endl;
  ptr=(int *) realloc(ptr, 3*sizeof(int)); cout<<"3"<<endl;
  ptr=(int *) realloc(ptr, 4*sizeof(int)); cout<<"4"<<endl;
  ptr=(int *) realloc(ptr, 5*sizeof(int)); cout<<"5"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to run your code. It is causing problems in the strcpy line. If you comment out that line. It works fine.

data[len]->string will now give you the correct answer. Here you have malloced an array for *data. Hence, the correct way to do this is strcpy((*data)[len].string, "A"). 
Notice the use of dot operator instead of arrow operator to dereference string.

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe that there should be an access violation in the use of strcpy in the second iteration of while loop itself. I wonder how it works for the second time and causes an error in the 3rd. I would be more than happy if someone could explain it to me .